# Selecting Child Object in Presto Query

Tags: sql, presto

I have the following object in the table

```
select items from item_table;
```

Result:

```
[{item={departmentNumber=2, description=Guitar, itemNumber=563082}}]
```

I want to select description from this i tried :

```
select items.item.description from item_table;
```

Giving the following error:

```
Expression items is not of type ROW
```

How to select the child Json Object here

Comment: Is `items` of type `json`, `varchar` or `array(...)`?

Comment: @PiotrFindeisen it's `array()`

Comment: @PiotrFindeisen I tried that `SELECT h.description FROM item_table, UNNEST(items) as h` it gives me.  ` Unhandled type for Block: array(row `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the error message provided in the comment, this should work

```
SELECT items[1].item.description
FROM item_table
```

If you want all of them, this could be helpful.

```
SELECT item.description
FROM item_table
CROSS JOIN UNNEST(items) AS t(item)
```

Comment: if i have more than one column how to do that for that i getting  `Column alias list has 1 entries but 't' has 3 columns available`

Comment: this works fine `SELECT items[1].item.description FROM item_table;` any general  way where i don't have to give indexes for more than one colums

Comment: If you hit `Column alias list has 1 entries but 't' has 3 columns available`, try replacing replace `t(item)` with `t(departmentNumber, description, itemNumber)`.

Comment: can you help with this -https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62084520/presto-unnest-array-inside-array